# How to add transformation on top of already existing ones in JS plugins

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the plugin arctype.js which allows for you to curve text on the page. However, it uses transformations and now I am unable to add any other transform effects using css `transform`. Here is the code that I tried:

```
<center><h2 id = "days" class = "numbers">1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 </h2></center>

 <style> 
    .numbers .char1{
        transform: translate(0px, 0);
        transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s ease;
    }

    .numbers .char1:hover{
      transform: scale(0.7);

    }
<style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to override the plugin's css and make sure that your style declarations *always* gets most priority you can use `!important`

```
.classname {
 transform: scale(0.7) !important;
}
```

Comment: When i use the !important it overides the plugin which now doesn't work. Is there another work around?